# noob: node.js writeHead stopping my code

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok, I'm new to Node.js so excuse the noob question. Heres my simple code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

// simple node.js server

server = http.createServer(function (request, response){

var get_text = function (errors, contents){
    response.write(contents);
    response.end('hello world');
}
// get_text is the callback
fs.readFile('log.txt', get_text);
response.write('End of the callback');

response.writeHead(200);
});

server.listen(8000);

console.log('Server running at port 8000');
```

As it stands, when I run the script in my terminal it will start the server properly but when I go to my localhost:8000 in my browser (chrome) it comes up as "webpage not available".

If I comment out the writeHead command it works fine.

Why?

Comment: writeHead writes headers and has to be called before any `write` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're attempting to `.writeHead()` after `.write()`:

```
response.write('End of the callback');

response.writeHead(200);
```

[`.writeHead()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_reasonphrase_headers) has to be first:

```
response.writeHead(200);
response.write('End of the callback\n');
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help. Node.js is a bit cryptic for me at this point but I'll bushwhack my way through it sooner or later.

Comment: @JDillon522 Yeah, Node.js is intended to be rather low-level and technical. But, that's also why [NPM](https://npmjs.org/) installs with Node and why they promote [so many packages/modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#web-frameworks).